# Full width block near floated one

Tags: css

I have two rows like this

```
<div class="container me">
    <div class="message">
    </div>

    <div class="time">
    </div>
</div>

<br />

<div class="container he">
    <div class="message">
    </div>

    <div class="time">
    </div>
</div>
```

with css like this

```
* {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}

.container {
  width:500px;
  height:50px;
  outline:1px solid green;
}

.message {
  width:250px;
  height:50px;
  border:1px solid red;
  display:inline-block;

  border-radius:5px;
  position: relative;
}

.time {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background:orange;
}

.container.me .time {
  float:right;
}

.container.he .time {
  float:left;
}
```

and i am trying to make message block full possible width (100% minus time block), is it possible?

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Nerfair/t0t0q632/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set width for `.message` to `width: calc(100% - 52px);` - this 52px is a width of your `.time` div (50px) + 2px for borders of `.message` (left and right)

Edit: For IE8 support you cannot use that, so you can try the tricky thing like this: https://jsfiddle.net/L2pqhnsq/

Comment: Sadly i need to support IE8 :(

Comment: oh... :( then you can only make some tricky thing like you can see here: https://jsfiddle.net/L2pqhnsq/